# TikZ — Intersection line of a cone and a helicoid, too many lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, intersections

Here is the image I'm working on: it's an archimedean spiral, shown as an orthogonal projection of an intersection line of a cone and a helicoid.

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm, z=1mm]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis equal image,
        view       = {22}{12},
        axis lines = none,
        xmax       = 50,
        xmin       = -50,
        ymax       = 50,
        ymin       = -50,
        zmax       = 100,
        zmin       = 0,             
        xtick      = \empty,
        ytick      = \empty,
        ztick      = \empty
    ]

    % Ground
    \addplot3+[
        ytick      = \empty,
        yticklabel = \empty,
        domain     = 0:12*pi,
        samples    = 1000,
        samples y  = 0,
        mark       = none,
        draw       = none,
        fill       = black!10   
    ]
    ({12*pi*sin(deg(x))}, {12*pi*cos(deg(x)}, {0});

    % Shadow
    \addplot3+[
        ytick      = \empty,
        yticklabel = \empty,
        domain     = 0:12*pi,
        samples    = 1000,
        samples y  = 0,
        mark       = none,
        line width = 0.2mm,
        line cap   = round,
        black!40
    ]
    ({x*sin(0.1*pi*deg(x))}, {x*cos(0.1*pi*deg(x)}, {0});

    % Intersection line
    \addplot3+[
        ytick      = \empty,
        yticklabel = \empty,
        domain     = 0:12*pi,
        samples    = 1000,
        samples y  = 0,
        mark       = none,
        line width = 0.2mm,
        line cap   = round,
        red
    ]
    ({x*sin(0.1*pi*deg(x))}, {x*cos(0.1*pi*deg(x)}, {x});

    % Base of a cone
    \addplot3+[
        ytick      = \empty,
        yticklabel = \empty,
        domain     = 0:12*pi,
        samples    = 1000,
        samples y  = 0,
        mark       = none,
        line width = 0.1mm,
        black
    ]
    ({12*pi*sin(deg(x))}, {12*pi*cos(deg(x)}, {12*pi});

    % Helicoid outer line
    \addplot3+[
        ytick      = \empty,
        yticklabel = \empty,
        domain     = 0:12*pi,
        samples    = 1000,
        samples y  = 0,
        mark       = none,
        line cap   = round,
        line width = 0.1mm,
        black
    ]
    ({12*pi*sin(0.1*pi*deg(x))}, {12*pi*cos(0.1*pi*deg(x)}, {x});

    % Helicoid plane
    \foreach \a in {0,1,...,48} {
        \edef\temp{\noexpand \draw[line width=0.05mm] ({(1/4)*\a*pi*sin(0.1*pi*deg(\a*pi/4))}, {(1/4)*\a*pi*cos(0.1*pi*deg(\a*pi/4)}, {\a*pi/4}) -- ({12*pi*sin(0.1*pi*deg(\a*pi/4))}, {12*pi*cos(0.1*pi*deg(\a*pi/4)}, {\a*pi/4});}
        \temp
    }

    %Cone walls
    \foreach \a in {0,1,...,13} {
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw [line cap=round, line width=0.05mm] (0, 0, 0) -- ({12*pi*cos(deg(\a*pi/7))}, {12*pi*sin(deg(\a*pi/7))}, {12*pi});}
        \temp
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: an intersection of a cone and a helicoid]

Now I'm looking for a way to add the helicoid.

The problem is: there are too many lines in the output image and you are hardly able to recognize the single parts of an image (it should be black and white by the way).

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please can you complete your code so it compiles and clarify your question. What should it look like? Are there too many lines in the image you posted? Should the red line be black? Or do you have some other code which is the problem but which we don't have?

Comment: @cfr Full source is there.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the line below `% Helicoid plane` to

```
\foreach \a in {0,2,...,48} {
```

And for making everything black and white, change the nearest `red` below `% Intersection line` to `black`.

The result is

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I added a screenshot of the output after your suggestions. You can always try an online service like ShareLaTeX or Overleaf, then you can test the code even if you don't have a LaTeX distribution available.